# AdMob AdView apears on top of ListView in Android

Tags: android, layout, adview

I am trying to get an AdView to appear at the bottom of my layout, its sort of working but for some reason my AdView is covering the last few rows of my ListView, instead of apearing right after it. I have tried a bunch of things including setting the ListView with height 0px. and weight 1, all with no luck. Any clues?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout  
android:id="@+id/home_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"

>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/banner" 
android:background="#000000" 
android:layout_height="45dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

    <TextView android:text="MAIN" 
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>

    <TextView android:text="HEADER" 
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"    
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>  

</LinearLayout>

 <View android:id="@+id/divider"
android:background="@drawable/bw_gradient"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="3dip"  

/>

<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
>
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/ad_layout"             
         android:gravity="bottom"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"             
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"           
         >

        <com.google.ads.AdView 
         android:id="@+id/adView2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ads:adUnitId="5555555555"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:loadAdOnCreate="false"             
         />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_holder">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/banner"
      android:background="#000000"
      android:layout_height="45dip"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView
        android:text="MAIN"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">
      </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">
      </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
      android:id="@+id/divider"
      android:background="@drawable/bw_gradient"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="3dip" />

    <ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
></ListView>

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_holder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
      android:id="@+id/adView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      ads:adUnitId="5555555555"
      ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:loadAdOnCreate="false" />
  </LinearLayout>
```